# Application is not launching in the ZAP Chrome/Firefox Broswer

Tags: zap

I am using ZAP 2.12.0 Cross Platform Package. I have installed openjdk version "17.0.2".
When I try to manually explore any web application, It opens the browser(Chrome or Firefox) but the application is not loading. I get the error message "Failed to read "http://xyx.com within 60 seconds, check to see if the site is available and if so consider adjusting ZAP's read timeout in the connection options panel.

[image]

Am I missing anything here?

Answer (score 0):

This is usually not a ZAP problem.

Is your web application actually running?

Can you connect to it using the IP address rather than the FQDN or hostname?

Can you connect to your application from the same machine using another tool like curl?

Do you need to configure an upstream proxy in order to connect to the web app?

Comment: I have tried in normal Chrome & Firefox browsers. The applications worked fine. This is happening only in the browser opened through ZAP. I tried for 3 to 4 different web applications.

Comment: Have those browsers been configured to use an upstream proxy? That might have been done automatically for you - check their configs. Also try curl from the command line.

Comment: I asked many people in our workplace, almost all have same issue. Cross Platform Package doesn't work properly in Open JDK 17. Earlier we were using ZAP in Oracle JDK. It worked fine without any issue in both Chrome & Firefox browsers.

Comment: How to update the ZAP Chrome driver compatible with the browser installed ?

Comment: Update the ZAP add-ons - we update the webdriver add-ons whenever new webdrivers are released. If for some reason you have to use an older browser then you will need to find the correct webdriver and install that yourself. The Selenium Options screen allows you to select your own webdriver file.